# Get all results from database but show 0 price for lowest prices

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script for a restaurant where you can add pizza's in 1+1 offer in your shopping cart and i want if there are 2 pizza's to display the most expensive one with real price and the cheapest with 0.01, and if for example the users adds 3 pizza's that cost 10$ and 3 that cost 11$ need to display 11$ for every pizza that cost that and 0.01 for the 3 pizza's that cost 10$, i tried everything but cant manage to figure this out.

```
$dbres1plus1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cos_cumparaturi WHERE extra='1plus1' AND ip='$user_ip'");
$numara_pizze = mysql_num_rows($dbres1plus1);
if($numara_pizze % 2 != 0) {

echo '<tr>

                      <td colspan="5"><sup style="color: red;"><strong>Ai adaugat '.$numara_pizze.' pizze in oferta, ai nevoie de '.$numara_pizze_total.' pizze pentru a completa oferta.</strong></sup></td>
                    </tr>';
}
                    }
echo '<tr id="'.$cos{'id'}.'">
                        <td colspan="3"><strong>'.$pizza{'nume'}.'</strong> <em>('.$marime.'cm)</em></td>
                        <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right;">'.$pizza{'pret'}*$happyhour.' lei</td>
                                                <td width="20">

                                                <a href="#" class="stergecos" id="'.$cos{'id'}.'">

                        &nbsp;<img style="margin-top:4px;" src="http://website/images/delete_icon.png" widht="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Sterge produs" /></a></td>
                      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>';                    
} 
}
```

i have a row in the database with the price. I tried to get lowest number and replace it but since its a while loop it replaces all prices.

Comment: Please show your code, tell how you pull the data and so on and so on. Short said, make it a question one would like to answer

Comment: Yes, please show the code that you are trying to fix...

Comment: Share your table structure and some data sample would be great.

Comment: Post edited with the code that pulls our the data.

Comment: show us your table `cos_cumparaturi` structure, here you wrote SELECT statement it does nothing with database, just read, but `I tried to get lowest number and replace it but since its a while loop it replaces all prices.` no you didn't - there is no try to get some MIN or MAX, and there is no loop in your code showing. and off course SELECT couldn't `and replace it`. So just ask your question clearly to help us help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just use the `ORDER BY` in `MYSQL`. If you order by `PRICE DESC` then you can show the first half correct, and the second half as `0.01`

Simple example:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT `Pizza`, `Price` FROM `orders` ORDER BY `Price` DESC';

//your code to exec query

//get the row count (example with mysqli)
$nrOfOrders = $result->num_rows;

//1 = pay 1
//2 = pay 1;
//3 = pay 2;
//4 = pay 2;
//etc
$fullPrice = ceil($nrOfOrders/2);

$index = 1;
//loop trough orders
foreach($result as $row)
  if ($index <= $fullPrice) {
    //show full price
  } else {
    //show 0.01
  }

  //increase index
  $index++;
}

?>
```

Comment: this doesnt work cause sometimes i have different prices but sometimes i have 2 pizza's with the same price say 10$ and i want 1 to show as 0.01 and the other with the full price of 10...

Comment: And why wouldnt this work then? It does exactly that. It shows the most expensive half of of the order with regular price and the rest as 0.01

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you can test the price and return what you want. I don't know what your table looks like but something like...

$sql="SELECT IF(price < MAX(price), 0,price) AS the_price FROM cos_cumparaturi WHERE extra='1plus1' AND ip='$user_ip' GROUP BY extra";

Untested as don't have table structure but something like this should work